# Find Control using javascript inside an ASP:Login control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, findcontrol, login-control

I have an ASP Login control box on the page which is customized.

Inside the Login control we have Username and password textboxes.

I want to find username and password controls with a javascript function.

```
var Username= document.getElementById("<%=UserName.ClientID%>");
```

But this code does not compile and gives compile time error

```
UserName not found in this context.
```

and if I write the client side id :

```
var username = document.getElementById("login_LoginUser_UserName");
```

it executes properly, but I want to find the client id rather than using a hardcoded id here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way which I know is:

```
 var Username = document.getElementById("<%= Login1.FindControl("UserName").ClientID %>");
 var Password = document.getElementById("<%= Login1.FindControl("Password").ClientID %>");
```

It will returns the client Id of the controls inside of `Login` control.

Comment: why would you post codebehind segments when its javascript the OP is looking for?

Comment: Who said that it's only codebehind? `var Username= document.getElementById("<%= Login1.FindControl("UserName").ClientID %>");`. Is it acceptable?

Comment: that comment is worth more the OP than your entire answer ;)

Comment: Thank you.I tried it and it should be document.getElementById('<%= LoginControl.FindControl("UserName").ClientID %>'); single quotes on the outside  and double on the inside.